# Rust avro serialization of Option<T> and custom schema

Tags: rust, avro, serde

I have a rust program that uses the apache-avro library to serialize/deserialize data. My main problem is that our schema for float and double values are as follows:

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "Topic",
    "namespace": "some.namespace",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "double0",
            "type": [
                "double",
                "null"
            ],
            "default": 0.0
        }
    ]
}
```

Basically, the default value is 0.0 and we accept null values (when there's a nan or invalid value produced by the client).

When writing the client with rust I was trying to replicate this behavior using `Option<f64>`, something like this:

```
struct Topic {
    double0: Option<f64>,
}
```

However, this ends up producing incompatible values because serde converts `Option<f64>` into a `"type": ["null", "double"]` schema.

I think the main problem is that if null comes first the `Record` produced by serde will look something like this `Record([("double0", Union(1, Double(1234.5)))])`, whereas following the schema above it should actually be `Record([("double0", Union(0, Double(1234.5)))])`; e.g. `Union(0, ...)` instead of `Union(1, ... )`.

I created a repository showcasing the problem: https://github.com/tribeiro/schema_test

You should be able to clone it and run it with `cargo run`.

I would really appreciate any help I could get with this one.

I tried creating my own `Option<T>` struct and force it to have `Some<T>` defined before `None` and a default implementation that gives `Some(T::default())`. However, this also produces invalid data. The record I got converted out of this by serde looks like this:

```
Ok(Record([("double0", Record([("type", Enum(0, "Some")), ("value", Union(0, Double(1234.5)))]))]))
```

I feel like I am close with this approach but I really don't know how to proceed.

I feel like I would need to write my own custom serialization/deserialization code but I am not sure how to do that.

Again, any help would be greatly appreciated!

## Update

I managed to get close to the behavior I wanted.

I created a `MyDouble` and `MyFloat` enums (the only values we support `null` for) that mimics `Option`, then implemented the serialize trait myself.

It looks something like this:

```
impl Serialize for MyFloat {
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: Serializer,
    {
        // 3 is the number of fields in the struct.
        match self {
            MyFloat::Some(value) => serializer.serialize_f32(*value),
            MyFloat::None => serializer.serialize_unit(),
        }
    }
}
```

When it serializes `Some(value)` it looks like this:

```
    let topic_myop = TopicMyOption {
        double0: MyDouble::Some(1234.5),
        float0: MyFloat::Some(5.4321),
    };
```

looks like:

```
Ok(Record([("double0", Double(1234.5)), ("float0", Float(5.4321))]))
```

and

```
    let topic_myop_none = TopicMyOption {
        double0: MyDouble::None,
        float0: MyFloat::None,
    };
```

looks like:

```
Ok(Record([("double0", Null), ("float0", Null)]))
```

So, I miss the `Union` part, however, as I mentioned before, it serialized and deserializes ok.

No super beautiful but functional.

Comment: I poked through the avro code a bit and I don't think this is possible. The problem is that serializing an Option does something fundamentally different from serializing other things ([1](https://docs.rs/apache-avro/0.16.0/src/apache_avro/ser.rs.html#189), [2](https://docs.rs/apache-avro/0.16.0/src/apache_avro/types.rs.html#192)), and even if you implement `Serialize` yourself, you can't get the behaviour you want. You may want to file this as a bug/feature request against avro. (If only `Value` implemented `Serialize`…)

Comment: Hi @Caesar, thanks for your help! I think I finally managed to get it into a workable state. It is not exactly clean and it doesn't exactly give the same result as `Option` but it is close enough and it is able to serialize/deserialize the data correctly.


Basically, I create a `MyDouble` and MyFloat` enums (the only types we support null values for) and then implemented the Serialize trait for them.